# How to get a running Spring-Data-Hadoop project with Cloudera CDH4 and Maven

Tags: java, hadoop, spring-data, cloudera

Since Spring-Data-Hadoop is not released yet, it's hard to find a running example configuration to use it with cloudera.

Which Dependencies I need to choose to get a running Spring-Data-Hadoop together with CDH4 (Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.1.3)?

By choosing different apporches I got this Exceptions:

1. NullPointer

   ```
   Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JobExecutor$2.run(JobExecutor.java:183)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:405)
       at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JobUtils.<clinit>(JobUtils.java:123)
       ... 2 more
   ```
2. Version missmatch 7 to 4

   ```
   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 7 cannot communicate with client version 4
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
       at $Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:238)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:372)
       at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JobFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobFactoryBean.java:208)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
   ... 12 more
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example how to configure it.

**Maven Setup:**

Notes:

- (Optinal) Exclude the hadoop-streaming and hadoop-tools from spring-data-hadoop
- Add hadoop-common and hadoop-hdfs with the generic version: 2.0.0-cdhX.X.X
- Add hadoop-tools and hadoop-streaming with the mr1 version: 2.0.0-mr1-cdhX.X.X
- Spring Data Hadoop support only MR1 currently. So be sure you don't included MR2 in other dependencies. Check this with `mvn dependency:tree`!

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example.main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.hadoop.version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.hadoop.version>
        <hadoop.version.generic>2.0.0-cdh4.1.3</hadoop.version.generic>
        <hadoop.version.mr1>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3</hadoop.version.mr1>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.hadoop.version}</version>

            <exclusions>
                <!-- Excluded the Hadoop dependencies to be sure that they are not mixed 
                    with them provided by cloudera. -->
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-streaming</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-tools</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>

        <!-- Hadoop Cloudera Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version.generic}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version.generic}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-streaming</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven SNAPSHOT Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**Spring Setup (applicationContext.xml):**

Replace the `fs.default.name` with your namenode domain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
        fs.default.name=hdfs://example.com:8020
    </hdp:configuration>

    <hdp:job id="wordCountJob" 
        mapper="com.example.WordMapper"
        reducer="com.example.WordReducer" 
        input-path="/user/christian/input/test"
        output-path="/user/christian/output2" />

    <hdp:job-runner job-ref="wordCountJob" run-at-startup="true"
        wait-for-completion="true" />
```

With this you should be able to access your cluster.

Some References:

- [Springsource Forum - Nullpointer Exception](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?134821-NullPointerException-in-Spring-Data-Hadoop-with-CDH4)
- [Cloudera Maven Repository](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Using+the+CDH4+Maven+Repository)

Answer (score 0):

hey you can download it from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book.

Building and running it is given in the Read me document.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, please consider adding the important points/a summary of it to the answer. Doing so would make sure that your answer remains useful even if the provided link becomes inactive. Link only answers are discouraged in SO.

Comment: This answer is enigmatic, at very least. It does not answer the question.